# Entity Framework: Inheritance and Include

Tags: entity-framework, inheritance, include

Assume the following hierarchy:

```
class Department { EntityCollection<Employee> Employees; }

class Employee { string Name; }

class RemoteEmployee : Employee { Country Location; EntityReference<Country> CountryReference; }
```

So, department contains a list of employees. There is a hierarchy of employee types, some types reference other entities. 
Let's suppose we need to load department with its employees. OK, not a problem:

```
dataContext.Departments.Include("Employees")
```

This returns concrete employee types (i.e. RemoteEmployee for Remote ones).
Now we need to load Location with Remote employees.

```
dataContext.Departments.Include("Employees").Include("Employees.Location") - Error: no such property in Employee
dataContext.Departments.Include("Employees").Include("RemoteEmployees.Location") - Error: no such property in Department
```

What should I specify in Include to load Location with RemoteEmployee?

Comment: What's wrong with ALex's solution.  Why don't you accept it so he can get reward from it ?

Answer (score 13):

I'm pretty sure what CatZ suggests doesn't work.

I don't think you can do this using Include, but you can achieve the same effect using a projection trick see this [How to Sort Relationships in the Entity Framework](http://blogs.msdn.com/alexj/archive/2009/02/25/tip-1-sorting-relationships-in-entity-framework.aspx)

What you need to do is something like this:

```
var results = from d in ctx.Departments
              select new {
                   d, 
                   employees = d.Employees.Select(
                      e => new {
                          e, 
                          location = e is RemoteEmployee ? 
                                     (e as RemoteEmployee).Location : 
                                     null
                     }
                   )
              };


foreach (var result in results)
{
    var re = result.d.Employees.First() as RemoteEmployee;
    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} works from {2}", 
           re.Firstname, re.Surname, re.Location.Name);
}
```

Notice that you don't need to use the anonymous types to get the data, essentially doing the projection has a side-effect of filling the collections on you department because of a feature of the Entity Framework called fixup.

Hope this helps
Alex

Comment: Thanks, that helps. I can't say I'm happy with this solution.
Now I just manually load required properties using this:
department.Employees.OfType<RemoteEmployee>.ForEach(re => re.LocationReference.Load());
It seems like more readable but at the speed cost.

Comment: I am trying to implement the above solution, but in the above example where you have `d.Employees.Select(` my navigation property is not a collection because of the multiplicity, so it does not have a Select( method.  If it was instead a single employee like `d.Employee` and I wanted to check and see if Employee was a certain derived type, and if so then load it's navigation properties.