# Using the Include Method to load related objects in EntityFramework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

Below is a section of my Entity Framework Model. You'll notice I have a "header" table, which is related to many "AssetHolding" records, which itself can be one of 3 types - for which im using inheritance (TpH). *Please ignore the fact that all 3 inherited types look identical - this is intentional*

[image: Entity model]

When editing this data, I need to pull one specific header by Id, and all associated AssetHoldings. The method to do so looks like this:

```
public AssetValuationHeader GetValuationHeaderById(int id)
{
    return this.AssetValuationHeaders
        .Include("AssetHoldings")
        .Where(vh => vh.Id == id)
        .FirstOrDefault();
}
```

This correctly loads everything highlighted with a red border in the image above.

The problem im having is that I  *also* need to load the bit highlighted with a green border in the above image. As you can see this is only related off of one of the 3 inheritance tables.

I tried this:

```
public AssetValuationHeader GetValuationHeaderById(int id)
{
    return this.AssetValuationHeaders
        .Include("AssetHoldings")
        .Include("AssetHoldings.SwapAssetHoldingNotionals")
        .Where(vh => vh.Id == id)
        .FirstOrDefault();
}
```

> A specified Include path is not valid. The EntityType
>   'CoreValuationModel.AssetHolding' does not declare a navigation
>   property with the name 'SwapAssetHoldingNotionals'.

Is this even possible using the `Include` method? (ie, without using LazyLoading) Any workaround if not?

Comment: It doesn't work because of entity inheritance. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/944332/entity-framework-inheritance-and-include

Answer (score 1):

jamie,

**[spoiler]** - this is coded from complete memory and may not actually compile at all!!

Anyway, I've had situations where I've had to load the graph a few levels deep and seem to remember doing something along the following lines:

```
public AssetValuationHeader GetValuationHeaderById(int id)
{
    return this.AssetValuationHeaders
        .Include("AssetHoldings")
        .Include("AssetHoldings").Select(sa => sa.SwapAssetHoldingNotionals)
        .Where(vh => vh.Id == id)
        .FirstOrDefault();
}
```

or:

```
public AssetValuationHeader GetValuationHeaderById(int id)
{
    return this.AssetValuationHeaders
        .Include("AssetHoldings")
        .Include("AssetHoldings").Include("SwapAssetHoldingNotionals")
        .Where(vh => vh.Id == id)
        .FirstOrDefault();
}
```

as i said, don't shoot the messenger (will check this out away from my 'phone' later)